# for loop - why does this print 12 and not 3?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int result = 0, x, y;
  for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
      result++;
    }
  }
  printf("%d", result);
  return 0;
}
```

This prints `12`. Why does it print `12`?

If I go through it step by step it seems like it should stop adding `1` to result when `y` is at `3`, so the loop was iterated 3 times. (Or it should print 2 if I miscalculated something.)

Comment: because of 3*4 = 12 ? please count x=0 x=1 x=2 x=3 , and y=0 y=1 y=2 , it is first lesson that you should learn about loops

Comment: It loops 4 times the inner loop which loops 3 times so in total results get's 12x incremented

Comment: Learn about nested loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of your variables throughout the loops are like follows:

```
x y result
----------
0 0 1
0 1 2
0 2 3
1 0 4
1 1 5
1 2 6
2 0 7
2 1 8
2 2 9
3 0 10 
3 1 11
3 2 12
```

So that's why `result` ends up being `12`.

To get `3` you should increment `result` just with the first loop and from `1` to `3` (`0 <= x < 3` or `1 <= x <= 3`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int result = 0, x, y;
  for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      result++;
  }
  printf("%d", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's every time good to write the iteration number! (Very nice made) BTW: `x=1` so you have 3

Comment: I agree, @Rizier123 , it clarifies many things! And also thanks, I updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

Note the code block containing loop(s) very carefully. There are *two* `for` loops, also called *nested* `for` loop.

```
for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
```

The outer `for` loop will execute till `x<4`, i.e. 4 time, all over again. Each time, the inner `for` loop will execute till `y < 3`, i.e, `3` times(`y` being initialized to `0`).

so, `(4 times outer loop)` * `(3 times inner loop)` = 12 times increment.

Next, please note, the `printf()` statement is placed after the outer `for` loop. So, the value of `result` will be the final output after both the loops have finished execution.

`12` time `+1` increment to `0` == value of `12`. :-)

BTW, to get a value of `3` [or better to say, to see the `result` value getting incremented by `3`], you can use a `printf()` after *inner* `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Table.. Table.. Table:

```
  x | y | res
 ---+---+----
  0 | 0 | 1   x < 4 ? y < 3 ? yes
    | 1 | 2   x < 4 ? y < 3 ? yes
    | 2 | 3   x < 4 ? y < 3 ? yes
    | 3 | X   x < 4 ? y < 3 ? NO
  1 | 0 | 4   ...
    | 1 | 5
    | 2 | 6
  2 | 0 | 7
    | 1 | 8
    | 2 | 9
  3 | 0 | 10
    | 1 | 11
    | 2 | 12
```

Answer (score 0):

First for loop run four times, Second for loop runs three times.

So second for loop increment that variable up to 3 times.

So the first iteration gives the `result=3` when `i=0,`, Second time it will increment three, so `result=6` when `i=1`,third iteration `result=9` when `i=2` , and final iteration
`result=12` when `i=3` then loop ends. So the output is 12.